# Determine the dimension of a subspace of $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The exercise is the following. I have to find the dimension of the subspace 
$$
V\subset\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^3),\qquad V=\{L\in\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^3):\operatorname{Im}L\subset Z\}
$$
where 
$$
Z=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x_1+x_2+x_3\leq1,\ x_1+x_2+x_3\geq-1\}.
$$
**My attempt.** I know that $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Im}L\leq3$ and it cannot be $3$, because otherwise it means that all the space $\operatorname{Im}L$ is between two planes. So its dimension can be only $2$ or $1$. Now, the book excludes the case $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Im}L=1$ and it it says that $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Im}L=2$. I cannot understand why. Someone can help me?

Thank You

Comment: It's not clear to me too. Moreover, if $L=0$, then $\text{Im} L = \{0\}$ is of course included in $Z$... Could you provide more context?

Comment: @paf No, the exercise says only to determine the dimension of $V$ and the result is $6$. Have you some idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for $\dim \text{im }L$ to be $2,1$ or even $0$, but the dimension of the image of any particular $L\in V$ is irrelevant.

The key idea is that $\text{im }L$ must be a subspace of $W\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}$, which is a subspace of dimension $2$. Furthermore, $L$ can be any map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $W$, so
$$
\dim V=\dim \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb R^3,W)=\dim\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb R^3,\mathbb R^2),
$$ since $W\cong \mathbb R^2$. Can you figure out $\dim\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb R^3,\mathbb R^2)$?

Comment: In my opinion,  $\operatorname{Im}L$ is not a subspace of $W$, but it is exactly the plane $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$. Indeed, as a subspace, it has to contain $0$ and, as a subspace of $Z$, it has to be parallel to the two planes $x_1+x_2+x_3=-1$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$. Moreover, its dimension cannot be $1$, because otherwise it would be a line passing to $0$ and to $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$. But there are infinitely many lines of this type. Is it right?

Comment: The dimension can be $1$. Let $L$ be the map with matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then $L\in V$ and $\text{im } L=\{(x,-x,0):x\in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: There are infinitely many lines of that type, and all of them are possibilities for the image of $L$, so it is possible for the image to be 1-dimensional.

Comment: Ok, so why is its dimension $6$? I know that $\operatorname{Im}L$ can have dimension $1$, but I do not understand why this case is excluded...

Comment: @Redeldio See my edit for a rewording.

Comment: I saw your edit and I understand your attempt. Anyway, my book says that $\operatorname{Im}L$ has dimension $2$ and does not consider the case $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Im}L=1$. In this way, it finds a basis for $\operatorname{Im}L$ and completes it in order to get a basis $B$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then, it considers the canonical basis $B_{\operatorname{can}}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and finds the associated matrix of the identity map w.r.t. the basis $B_{\operatorname{can}}$ and $B$. In this way, it finds a matrix similar to that wrote by @JanBohr in the following post.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\nu=(1,1,1)$, check that a subspace $U$ is contained in $Z$ if and only if $\nu\perp U$. Complete $\nu$ to an orthogonal basis $\{\nu,u_1,u_2\}$. Conclude that $\mathrm{Im}~L\subset Z$ if and only if 
$$
L = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0& 0 \\
* & *&* \\
* & *&* \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in the basis $\{\nu,u_1,u_2\}$. Hence $\dim V= 6$.